# How to test a gRPC client in a parallel for with NUnit?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, nunit, grpc

I would like to test when many users access to the server at the same time, so I am trying this code:

```
[Test]
public void Agregar2RegistrosHorariosDeEntradaDe2EmpleadosAsync()
{
    try
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 2,
                    async iterador =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await miClienteLogin.LoginAsync(_nombreUsuario, _password);
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail("No se debió producir ninguna excepción.");
    }
}
```

But I don't get any exception and the log in the server is this:

```
[13:38:29 DBG] Connection id "0HMPPMB4T" accepted.
[13:38:29 DBG] Connection id "0HMPPMB4T" started.
[13:38:29 DBG] Connection 0HMPPMB4T established using the following protocol: Tls13
[13:38:29 DBG] Connection id "0HMPPMB4T" reset.
[13:38:29 DBG] Connection id "0HMPPMB4T" is closed. The last processed stream ID was 0.
[13:38:29 DBG] The connection queue processing loop for 0HMPPMB4TUI6R completed.
[13:38:29 DBG] Connection id "0HMPPMB4T" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
[13:38:29 DBG] Connection id "0HMPPMB4T" stopped.
```

But If I run the same code outside the parallel for, it works as expected.

I guess it has to be a problem when I execute the client command inside a parallel for.

How could I run it inside the parallel for? Or how could I test when many users are requesting something to the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parallel.For` is not task-aware so it will not actually wait for `LoginAsync` to finish before ending the loop (it will just start tasks and that's it). Use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` or just `Task.WhenAll`. Something like the following:

```
[Test]
public async Task Agregar2RegistrosHorariosDeEntradaDe2EmpleadosAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
            .Select(_ => miClienteLogin.LoginAsync(_nombreUsuario, _password)));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail("No se debió producir ninguna excepción.");
    }
}
```

P.S.

If you want to assert if something throws you can use `Assert.Throws`/`Assert.ThrowsAsync`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggsetion. I get en error in the .select that says it is not possible to infer the type of arguments by the usage.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía can you please share the full [mre]? What is the type returned but `LoginAsync`?

Comment: LoginAsync return a Task<bool>.

Comment: It works, I made a mistake in the syntaxis. But my doubt is, with Enumerable.Range(0, 2) the method miClienteLogin() is executed in parallel? I don't understand how Enumerable.range() works really.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía `Enumerable.Range(0, 2)` is not parallel - it will sequentially generate a sequence of two elements and `Select` will start 2 task (assuming that `iClienteLogin.LoginAsync` is truly async and does not perform some kind of blocking internally), which will result int the tasks being executed in parallel (note that by convention methods returning `Task`'s should return so called "hot" tasks, i.e. started ones).